# Calculate the maximum and miimun of a function using derivates in c

Tags: c

I have a function returning `2*x + log(x+10)`. Is possible to find the maximum and the minimum of this function using the derivatives ?
This is my code  to calculate the derivative.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>

float f(float x)
{
    return 2*x +log(x+10);
}

void main()
{
    float x0 ;//point where i want to calculte the derivative
    float h = 0.00001;  

    printf("derivative in the point  %f is %f \n", x0 , (f(x0+h)-f(x0))/h);
}
```

But at this point I don't know how to go ahead.

Comment: I assume your actual code initializes `x0` to some valid value before calculating?

Comment: This is more a math question than a C question. This is one of first topics on Machine Learning courses. Too long to explain here... local minimums, overshot, ...

Comment: You do know, the maxima/minima of a function occur where it's derivative is 0, well you need ot use a root finding algorithm.

Comment: @iharob BTW, if a function's derivative is 0, it's not always the min/max, could be the inflection point too.

Comment: @szczurcio I don't think so, as I think of it, remember that I am not a mathematician, but a physicist, I see that derivative of a function equalt to `0` means, that the tangent line at the point where the derivative is `0` is parallel to the `x` axis, hence it's either a minimum or a maximum. And also, if it's a maximum or a minimum you can check with the second derivative.

Comment: so I assume that it is quite difficult,Indeed if i want to calculate without derivative , where the function has the meximum value or the minimum for example in the range [0,5]

Comment: @iharob No, it is possible that, for a given `x0`, the derivative will be equal to 0 and yet `f(x0)` won't be a local maximum / minimum. For example, consider `f(x) = x^3`: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x^3 (will need to reenter the expression, SO messes up the link)

Comment: @iharob, what's the derivative of [`y=x^3`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3Dx^3) at `x=0`?  Also a physicist here :-)  I think @szczurcio meant saddle point instead of inflection point.

Comment: Certainly any delta `h` should be relative to `x` --> `float h = x*0.00001;`

Comment: What are the bounds of `x`? This function gets funky for `x <= -10`.

Comment: The maximum finite result of `float f()` occurs at `x == FLT_MAX/2`.  The minimum finite occurs at `nextafterf(-10.0, 0.0)`.  Perhaps OP is looking for _local_ maximums and minimums?

Comment: @szczurcio You are absolutely right, I didn't think of such function, in fact any odd power of `x` would exhibit what you describe at `x = 0`.